# NodeJS using setInterval for chatroom timer

Tags: node.js, socket.io, chat

I want to create a timer for chat rooms. There can be many chat rooms, perhaps ~500 rooms. I want the chat to last 5 minutes and after that, the chat closes. From the question here [how to set timer for each room in Socket.io, Nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28520287/how-to-set-timer-for-each-room-in-socket-io-nodejs), it seems that `setInterval` is a possible solution. However, since NodeJS is single threaded, I am worried that the load on the server is too much, especially since I am also taking care of chats using `socket.io`. Is this a legitimate concern? If so, should I offload the time keeping function to another thread using something like `webworker-thread`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

~500 `setInterval` set to random times(according to chat rooms creation I suppose) is not an amount that should concern you.

Of course that is also dependent on the machine you run the node in but in general it should be fine. But if you do have performance issues, I suggest scaling up servers instead of dealing with threads.

Regarding the chat handling - just avoid heavy processing and synchronous methods and you'll be fine :)